# How can I dynamically fill a transposed HTML table with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling with HTML table formatting.
So I've got the following JQuery function that dynamically fills the HTML format where information is filled along the row.

`file.js`

```
function createHTML( data ) {
    var next_row_num = 1;
       $.each( data.matches, function(i, item) {
            var this_row_id = 'result_row_' + next_row_num++;
            $('<tr/>', { "id" : this_row_id } ).appendTo('#matches tbody');
            $('<td/>', { "text" : item.accession } ).appendTo('#' + this_row_id);
            $('<td/>', { "text" : item.description } ).appendTo('#' + this_row_id);
            $('<td/>', { "text" : item.structural } ).appendTo('#' + this_row_id);
       }
 }
```

`HTML`

```
    <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Accession</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Structural</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- this will be filled in by javascript when there are results -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to have the information filled in down the column instead down the row so that the HTML is in the following format.

```
      <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Accession</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Description</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Structural</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           </tbody>
         </table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

`data.matches`

```
for(my $i=0; $i < scalar(@accession); $i++){
    #hash ref:  $href->{ $key } = $value;
    my $href = {};
    $href->{'accession'}=$accession[$i];
    $href->{'description'}=$description[$i];
    $href->{'structural'}=$structural[$i];
    $href->{'chemical'}=$chemical[$i]
    $href->{'functional'}=$functional[$i];
    $href->{'charge'}=$charge[$i];
    $href->{'hydrophobic'}=$hydrophobic[$i];
    $href->{'dayhoff'}=$dayhoff[$i];
    $href->{'sneath'}=$sneath[$i];
    push(@$matches, $href);
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us What you got in `data.matches`, so we can find your problem easily.

Comment: @RohanKumar It's an arrayref containing hashrefs. Edited/included the code.

Comment: @Steve you want the data to be displayed in the thead much like key value pairs correct. You dont want to use tbody at all?

Comment: @PSL I can't wrap my head around the function to transpose it, so I'm not sure which would be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add an `id` to your `table`

```
<table id="matches">
<!-- Add an id in this element so your jquery will add data to this -->
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Accession</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Structural</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- this will be filled in by javascript when there are results -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The table is part of a section of id=matches

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would get your result:

```
$('#matches thead').append('<tr/>').append('<td/>', { "text" : item.accession } );
$('#matches thead').append('<tr/>').append('<td/>', { "text" : item.description} ); 
$('#matches thead').append('<tr/>').append('<td/>', { "text" : item.structural} );
```

That said, having rows like this under thead doesn't really make sense. I am afraid you're confusing thead (table head) with th (headers for table columns or rows).